# How can I round up numbers to the next half-integer?

Tags: python, rounding

In Python `floor()` and `ceil()` round to the next higher or lower integer.

How to round up any value between 1.01 - 1.5 to 1.5 and 1.51 - 2.0 to 2.0 etc.?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Multiply by two, `ceil()`, divide by two:

```
0.5 * ceil(2.0 * x)
```

Comment: and the same line of code, except calling floor instead of ceil, will 'round you down': 1.00 - 1.49 to 1 and 1.5 - 1.99 to 1.5, etc.